# Validating PayPal Pay Now and other cut and paste payment buttons as legitimate code

Tags: validation, paypal, paste

We have a site where we allow members to sell items they have made.

The items are displayed in a container including a name, description, images and price. The container also contains space for a Purchase button.

The content of each container is controlled by the member in an editor. Part of the editor is a text area where they can cut and paste a PayPal Pay-Now (or similar from other service) button code.

We already have all of this working; when the container is displayed the Pay Now button is shown and is functional.

My question is: How best to validate the code the member pastes into the editor as legitimate pay button code and not something malicious before it’s saved to DB.

I’ve set up a dropdown where the member selects the source of the code (PayPal, Stripe, etc) which would allow validation based on the selected source.

What I need is a resource for the validation code itself. Has someone done anything like this, some regex out there or maybe a service?

This is a net 5.0 site using razor pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sites builders either allow an arbitrary HTML/JS widget, or provide their own payment service integrations that implement payment buttons.

You will not find anyone validating button code, it's not done.

For PayPal Checkout, see the documentation on the `payee` object for sending funds to another account: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/

This `payee` object can be used in a client-side integration with no server, if you don't want to implement a backend; see https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client for an example